# React-native-fetch-blob gives error to create .apk file

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I have created an app which captures photo and upload to aws s3. For this I have used react-native-fetch-blob. But it gives error . Therfore, I unistalled it and install rn-fetch-blob. After uninstalling also it gives the same error. How to resolve this?

I have followed the below steps to uninstall the react-native-fetch-blob module.

```
1) react-native unlink <Module Name>

2) npm unlink <Module Name>

3) npm uninstall --save <Module name>
```

It give below error ,

[image]

Comment: try from android studio instead of cmd or gitbash

Comment: what is is your compileSdkVersion in build.gradle file??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by removing these two line of codes from MainApplication.java and build.gradle files after executing above commands

```
1. In MainApplication.java,

   I removed, new RNFetchBlobPackage(), method under getPackages() method.

2. In build.gradle file,

   I removed,implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob') 

   (Becuase, I wanted to use new package i.e rn-fetch-blob.)
```

It is working completely fine now.